# Highcharts SetData Only Works One Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using a button to change the series on a `High Charts` graph using the `series[0].setData()` function. It does change the data and update the graph, but when I try to use a second button to reset my back data, nothing seems to happen. Why can the `Series` only be updated once?

```
  $('#button').click(function() {
      chart.series[0].setData(mydata1);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ypsm98a/

EDIT:

Still looking for an answer, but a easy work around is to have the button first use `chart.destroy();` then recreate a completely new chart.

Comment: It's not that it cannot be called twice (it can be called as many times as you want), it's that, perhaps via some sort of reference conflation, the **mydata** variable is being updated to the values of the **mydata1** variable by the time the buttons are clicked (you can see this by logging the variable contents on button click:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9ypsm98a/5/ )

Comment: @jlbriggs Thanks. I have to access the logs through Chrome Developer tools right or does JSFiddle have something built in? Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't know what's going on for sure, but it seems that when the first update is happening, it is overwriting the **mydata** object with the **mydata1** object, rather than just updating the chart data object.

Comment: On reflection, this problem is the reason that I have always gone with destroying and rebuilding charts when I update the data from pre-defined data sets :)

Comment: Have you consider using $.extend()? That should help you with this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/9ypsm98a/8/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński $.extend works. Can you explain how it works?

Comment: Hi Tony, Thank you for your message. You should be able to find more specific information about $.extend in the link below: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the array/objects are being passed by reference on first creating the chart. After that, High Charts appears to be only updating the existing objects, overwriting the originals. Try the following jsfiddle. I first create the chart using empty objects. Then the buttons work as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/308zr285/

```
var emptyData = [{},{},{}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      backgroundColor: null,
      type: 'treemap'
    },
    series: [{
      type: "treemap",
      layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
      alternateStartingDirection: true
    }],
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit consumption'
    }
  });
  chart.series[0].setData(emptyData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution does work. Due to having to initialize the `emptyData` variable to length of the datasets, it will not work with datasets of different lengths.

Comment: A few years later and this doesn't seem to work. Using the initial empty data, it still only works once, even in the JSFiddle.